# Cobalt and system DIAL

Tags: cobalt

I have a board with Cobalt and DIAL server. If Cobalt isn't started DIAL server just runs Cobalt with appropriate parameters. But what should I do if Cobalt is already started? I mean how can I pass a new URL from DIAL to already run Cobalt?

Answer (score 1):

Starboard provides a mechanism to inject links into an already running application, via a `kSbEventTypeLink` event. The Linux implementation binds a local port, and every null- or newline- terminated string written to that socket gets sent to the application as a link event. This reference implementation is available in `starboard/shared/starboard/link_receiver.{cc,h}`. If you have a preferred method of system events or IPC, you can create a replacement that utilizes that instead.